# What has gone wrong in my index and match formula?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

The index & match formula listed below was working correctly until I updated the table with an additional column.  The Table name is *Table 4*. *Actual End Date* & *Name* are the header names for the columns.  Any help would be appreciated.

```
=INDEX(Table4[[Project]:[Actual End Date]], 
MATCH(1,(Table4[Project]=$F8)*(Table4[Name]="Create and execute QC test plan"),0),8)
```

Comment: Try entering it as array formula by pressing `Ctrl+Shift+Enter` instead of just `Enter` when confirming the formula.

Comment: Thank you long days